# Sorting Column Data from Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlsxwriter

Is there a way to take the columns from an excel sheet, write the columns as lists, sort them, and then rewrite them to another excel sheet? This is what I've tried so far, but it only writes the last column of data. I do not need the first 2 rows of data, as they are just headers.

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('exceldata.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

col=[]

for i in range(2,ws.ncols):
    col=ws.col_values(i)

    for x in range(2):
        col.pop(0)

    col.sort()

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test_sorting.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write_column('A1',col)
    workbook.close()
```

**UPDATE: This is successful, but does anyone know how this can be simplified?**

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('exceldata.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)


col1=ws.col_values(2)
for x in range(2):
    col1.pop(0)
col1.sort()

col2=ws.col_values(3)
for x in range(2):
     col2.pop(0)
col2.sort()

col3=ws.col_values(4)
for x in range(2):
     col3.pop(0)
col3.sort()

col4=ws.col_values(5)
for x in range(2):
    col4.pop(0)
col4.sort()

col5=ws.col_values(6)
for x in range(2):
     col5.pop(0)
col5.sort()

columns=[]
for i in range(2,7):
    col=ws.col_values(i)
    columns.append(col)

print(columns)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test_sorting.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write_column('A2',col1)
worksheet.write_column('B2',col2)
worksheet.write_column('C2',col3)
worksheet.write_column('D2',col4)
worksheet.write_column('E2',col5)
```

workbook.close()

Comment: You don't need to pop any values. You can simply retrieve values starting with the second element: `ws.col_values(3, 1)` returns a list of values starting with D2. While I think xlrd is the best package for reading Excel files, it doesn't have the best documentation. You should check out the xlrd section of the old [tutorial PDF](https://github.com/python-excel/tutorial). Yeah, it's out of date, but it's still better than the "official" xlrd documentation.

Comment: That loop at the end, which builds `columns`, is the right idea. You can use `columns` instead of `col1`, `col2`, etc. Note that while `columns` is a list, the elements inside it are also lists, and can thus be referred to and operated on individually. For example, in your code above, `columns[2]` contains the same data as `col3` (except for the popping and sorting). How do you pop and sort the data in `columns`? The simplest would be to do what you need to do to `col` immediately before appending it to `columns`, as you're building `columns`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to append() or extend() column names from your excel to the list 'col'. currently it is replacing the value of 'i' every time the FOR loop iterates.

maybe something like this:
col.append(ws.col_values(i))

P.S. This is my first answer on stack-overflow. hope it helps. I have not tested it (I will test it and update the answer if required).

Comment: I have tried this, but I get the following error: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'